PyTorch and Opacus for Differential Privacy
When testing an example code from the TensorFlow website using Jupyter Notebook, which is available at the following link: [LINK_1], I encountered an error. You can find my question about that error at the link below: [LINK_2].
As a result, I decided to write equivalent implementations for the same functionality using PyTorch with Opacus and PySyft. However, I unfortunately encountered another error.
Below is the code for implementing the same functionality of the example code from the TensorFlow website, but using PyTorch with Opacus and PySyft, along with the error message.
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from opacus import PrivacyEngine

# Define a simple model
class SimpleCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleCNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=3)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32*26*26, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = x.view(-1, 32*26*26)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        return torch.log_softmax(x, dim=1)

# Data loaders
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
train_dataset = datasets.MNIST('.', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)

# Initialize model, optimizer, and loss function
model = SimpleCNN()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
criterion = nn.NLLLoss()

# Initialize PrivacyEngine
privacy_engine = PrivacyEngine(
    model,
    batch_size=64,
    sample_size=len(train_loader.dataset),
    epochs=1,
    max_grad_norm=1.0,
)

privacy_engine.attach(optimizer)

# Training loop
model.train()
for epoch in range(1):
    for data, target in train_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = criterion(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

# Print privacy statistics
epsilon, best_alpha = optimizer.privacy_engine.get_privacy_spent(1e-5)
print(f"Epsilon: {epsilon}, Delta: 1e-5")



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 32
     29 criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
     31 # Initialize PrivacyEngine
---> 32 privacy_engine = PrivacyEngine(
     33     model,
     34     batch_size=64,
     35     sample_size=len(train_loader.dataset),
     36     epochs=1,
     37     max_grad_norm=1.0,
     38 )
     40 privacy_engine.attach(optimizer)
     42 # Training loop

TypeError: PrivacyEngine.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'batch_size'

